# How to merge an array of XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnodelist

I have an array of `XmlNodeList`.

Can I merge it into a single `XmlNodeList` object?

Answer (score 0):

some pseudo code. Don't know if the method calls are correct but method should work

```
joined xmlNodeList
for XmlNodeList nl in array
    for Node n in nl
        joined.insert n
```